# Opening different pdf file with previous and next button in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, pdf, button, arraylist, android-expandable-list-view

I'm trying to make a pdf book app with expandable list view and custom adapter. I've numbers of different pdf files in assets for different topics. I've made previous and next button layout in pdf view and I want those buttons to open previous and next pdf file. I'm a new learner so please help me with this.
Here is how it looks:

Fullview activity-

```
String fileName;
Intent intent;
PDFView pdfView;
Button nbutton,pbutton;
int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_view);

    pdfView=(PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pbutton=findViewById(R.id.pbutton);
    nbutton=findViewById(R.id.nbutton);
    intent=getIntent();
    
    fileName=intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
    pdfView.fromAsset(fileName+".pdf").load();
    
        }
    });
}
```

Main Activity -

```
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;


List<Cover>coverList;
List<Topics>topicsList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    expandableListView=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

    addData();

}

void addData()
{

    coverList=new ArrayList<>();

    topicsList=new ArrayList<>();
    topicsList.add(new Topics("1.","pdf1"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("2.","pdf2"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("3.","pdf3"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("4.","pdf4"));
    coverList.add(new Cover("Cover 1",topicsList));

   
    topicsList=new ArrayList<>();
    topicsList.add(new Topics("1.","pdf5"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("2.","pdf6"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("3.","pdf7"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("4.","pdf8"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("5.","pdf9"));
    topicsList.add(new Topics("6.","pdf10"));
    coverList.add(new Cover("Cover 2",topicsList));

     sendData();

}

void sendData()
{
    customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(coverList, MainActivity.this);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
```

& Custom Adapter :

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
List<Cover>coverList;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(List<Cover> coverList, Context context) {
    this.coverList = coverList;
    this.context = context;
}


//parent size count
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return coverList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return coverList.get(i).getTopicsList().size();
}

//position set
@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return coverList.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return coverList.get(i).getTopicsList().get(i1);
}

//id
@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return (i);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {

    view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cover_item,viewgroup, false);
    TextView coverName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.coverTitle);
    coverName.setText(coverList.get(i).getCoverName());

    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.arrow);

    if (b==true)
    {
        imageView.setRotation(90);
    }
    else if (b==false)
    {
        imageView.setRotation(0);
    }


    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
    view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.topic_item,viewgroup, false);
    TextView topicName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.topicTitle);
    topicName.setText(coverList.get(i).getTopicsList().get(i1).getTopicName());

    CardView cardView=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.topicClick);

    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent =(new Intent(context, FullView.class));
            intent.putExtra( "fileName",coverList.get(i).getTopicsList().get(i1).getFileName());
            context.startActivity(intent);



        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your button click listeners? I am answering on the basis of understanding of your question.

You have to change the `addData()` or you can use a counter to handle next and previous button. Let say `onNext()` increment counter by 1 and `onPrevious()` decrement counter by 1. This way you can use this counter as the index of the array to get the current pdfs.

I hope this is what you were asking. If not then share the button click handling code.

Comment: Ok. thanks for replying. Sorry I didnt share click listners. it is on custom adapter. I have now added it on my question.

Comment: I assume you are creating array in the MainActivity and load it to the adapter where you are passing the file name to Fullview activity to show in PdfView and there you want a button for next or previous pdf file in same activity(FullViewActivity).
If this what you are asking then you need to pass the whole array to the fullview activity with the current adapter position then you have to maintain a counter manually to get the pdf filename from the array by increament or decreament by 1 and load it to the PdfView. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: or just pass the current adapter position to the FullViewActivity and there add the same array creation method as in MainActivity and then use the current index to get the current pdf but still you have to write the manual counter logic for next and previous.